how to save redis cache data into mongodb using python
Check out how to subscribe to the expiring message in redis and trigger a code to load the message to mongo
provided the connection settings for your Redis instance, including the host, port, password, username, and database number.
I want to fetch data in real-time as it's inserted into Redi

Please give more details of what you have tried and didn't work, a code sample would be useful
